# PHP upload image success,but image is damaged！

Tags: php, upload

My website is very will in localhost or old server.now i move it to another server,I find upload image have a problem,sometimes,image is damaged.

run-time environment：windows server 2008 r2+apache2.4.9+php 5.5.12

[image]
[image]

```
<?php 


foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
      echo "Upload: " . $file["name"] . "<br />"; 
      echo "Type: " . $file["type"] . "<br />"; 
      echo "Size: " . ($file["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />"; 
      echo "Temp file: " . $file["tmp_name"] . "<br />"; 
      if (file_exists("upload/" . $file["name"])) 
      { 
          echo $file["name"] . " already exists. "; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
          move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], 
          "upload/" . $file["name"]); 
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $file["name"]; 
      }
```

}

?>

Comment: You should post some of your code if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For a while i have the same error. Wath for image function you use?

For fixx it use imagecreatetruecolor

```
 $altesBild=ImageCreateFromGIF("$PicPathIn"."$bild");
    $neuesBild=imagecreatetruecolor($neueBreite,$neueHoehe);
    imagecopyresampled($neuesBild,$altesBild,0,0,0,0,$neueBreite,
    $neueHoehe,$breite,$hoehe);
    ImageGIF($neuesBild,"$PicPathOut".""."$bild");
```